# Opencart Internal Server Error

Tags: php, paypal, module, opencart, payment

I have a problem with opencarted payment modules. I use version 3.0.0.0 and all modules are working fine except the ones that are in payment section. I get an Internal Server Error which at logs says: 
GET /admin/index.php?route=extension/extension/payment&user_token=LpWyMlFDTymqDs4I6Q1iUwUV6sI3VCet HTTP/1.0 http://eshop.capsport.gr/admin/index.php?route=marketplace/extension&user_token=LpWyMlFDTymqDs4I6Q1iUwUV6sI3VCet    Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/59.0.3071.115 Safari/537.36   303 Apache access
2017-07-12 10:27:38 Warning 94.70.255.140       mod_fcgid: stderr: PHP Fatal error: Can't use method return value in write context in /var/www/vhosts/paokbcstore.gr/eshop.capsport.gr/admin/controller/extension/payment/pp_express.php on line 1282, referer: http://eshop.capsport.gr/admin/index.php?route=marketplace/extension&user_token=LpWyMlFDTymqDs4I6Q1iUwUV6sI3VCet                Apache error
2017-07-12 10:28:34 Warning         RSA server certificate CommonName (CN) `Parallels Panel' does NOT match server name!?
Any possible solutions?

Answer (score 0):

I am using openCart v. 3.0.1.0
and Plesk for web hosting

I was having a similar 500 internal server error when I proccessing the checkout step 6.
My mistake was that, I was imported from an old version of openCart the data of the old Database to the new one.. But, in this senario the new version of openCart has some new table's columns as a saw carefully (such as inside table oc_order: tracking, payment_custom_field and so on). So, I have created these colums again, and now the step 6 from the checkout finally works again..

Iniside Plesk there is a choice saying: error-logs (or you can find it something like: log file, logs files e.t.c.). Inside this file I saw the mistake that says:
"mod_fcgid: stderr: PHP Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'Exception' with message 'Error: Unknown column 'tracking' in 'field list'" that's how I found the issue to my problem..

there are lots of things you could try though:

You could try some of the above...maybe could help you:

1. clear all caches
2. disable all extensions and inable them one by one, in order to see which one of them causes the problem..
3. download the same openCart version that you are using, and upload the checkout core files again.. maybe some of those files broke you code..(although this problem coming from extensions - modules)
4. check PHP version. Some users in openCart forum said that the problem solved by using the version of PHP 7.
5. see pp_express what are the needs of this payment proccess (link to github that my help you or maybe ask there: https://github.com/opencart/opencart/blob/master/upload/catalog/controller/extension/payment/pp_express.php)